# How to change submenu appear to left side instead of right

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with submenu that open to the right instead of the left. You can see that [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Barhamada/upece9te/1/)

Here is the html code:

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul class="parent-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Electronics</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Clothing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Books</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Support</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and the css:

```
p,
ul,
li,
div,
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}

#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}

#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

I would like the submenu appear to the left
can you please assist me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

just change all the "left" css rules to be "right" and float the main menu to the right instead of the left.

```
p,
ul,
li,
div,
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: right 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: right 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: right 200ms ease-in;
  transition: right 200ms ease-in;
}

#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: right 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: right 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: right 200ms ease-in;
  transition: right 200ms ease-in;
}

#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

I just quickly went through the css and did that in your fiddle  and it put the main menu on the right and the submenu to the left of the main menu.

Comment: This makes the submenu to sit offscreen to the right of the screen and the vertical scrollbar appears. You need to change the `right: -200px` to `right: 0;` to fix that. Also this solution might present a problem for very long submenu items, which would extend under the menu. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nc5rphf5/1/

Comment: @J. Niles - good point - i dint really read it all when i did the change - just a quick change to the position. Still, the point was not to present a finished, polished code but to provide a solution to the question that could then be finessed by the OP to give the style required. But fair call, i was too hasty in trying to present the option. Didn't think about it

Comment: @J. Niles - just looked at your fiddle and the submenu does not seem to appear.?

Comment: @J. Niles  - onya - still the point of all this is that by changing the css, it is easy to make the menu and submenu sit to the other side. Just takes looking at the css. - the OP should have been able to do that without calling on SO. If you can code a menu structure you can code the css  to make it display how you want it - or spend 5 minutes learning how to do it.

Comment: Absolutely! The only reason I mentioned brought it up was because I had was fiddling with it and had encountered those two issues (also the transition doesn't work in my solution) and I thought it might be a harder problem. But it's not.